# Deciding equality in free models of a (generalized) Lawvere theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, universal-algebra, decidability

Let $F : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ be functor of Lawvere theories $\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}$ (i.e. cartesian categories where every object is isomorphic to some power of a chosen object) that preserves finite limits and the chosen object. Precomposition $- \circ F$ turns every $\mathcal{D}$-model $A : \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \underline{\text{Set}}$ into a $\mathcal{D}$-model $A \circ F : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \underline{\text{Set}}$ in a functorial way. This functor preserves limits and directed colimits (because they are computed componentwise---use the fact that directed colimits commute with finite limits in $\underline{\text{Set}}$ for the latter). From [Adamek and Rosicky's book on locally presentable categories](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Locally_Presentable_and_Accessible_Categ.html?id=iXh6rOd7of0C&redir_esc=y), we know that

> - Every Lawvere theory's category of set-theoretic models is locally presentable. (Thm. 1.46)
> - A functor between locally presentable categories is right adjoint iff it preserves $\lambda$-directed colimits for some regular cardinal $\lambda$. (Thm. 1.66)

Therefore, the above-mentioned functor $- \circ F$ admits a left adjoint $G$. Now suppose that we have a model $A : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \underline{\text{Set}}$ and a way to decide whether two elements in its carrier are equal, and we can compute all functions induced by the structure as a model of $\mathcal{C}$. When can we construct $G$ in such a way that we can also decide equality in $G(A)$?

For example, this seems to be the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is the trivial theory whose models are sets, and $\mathcal{D}$ the theory of monoids, because we can easily decide whether two lists (elements of the free monoid) are equal if we can compare its elements.

The situation is less clear to me when $\mathcal{C}$ is the theory of monoids and $\mathcal{D}$ the theory of groups. This seems related to the world problem for groups, but easier.

I'm also very much interested in the generalization to multisorted Lawvere/algebraic theories (i.e. with $\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}$ arbitrary cartesian categories), and to essentially algebraic theories (where $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are finitely complete categories and $F$ preserves finite limits). For example, the free category over a graph has decidable equality, while I'm again unsure about the free groupoid over a category.

Answers to special cases are also welcome.

Comment: Presumably, the $A$ in the question is intended to be a model $\mathcal C\to\text{Set}$, not $\mathcal C\to\mathcal D$.  So one instance of your question would be whether a solution to the word problem for some presentation of a monoid would yield a solution to the word problem for the group with the same presentation. I'd certainly expect a negative answer in that special case.

Comment: Yes, the signature of $A$ was wrong. It should be fixed now. And yes, I think a positive answer to my question would entail what you said.

Comment: $G(A)$ is the quotient of the free $\mathcal D$-model on the set $A$ by the congruence generated by $F(\omega)(a_1,...,a_n)\sim\omega(a_1,...,a_n)$, for every $\mathcal C$-operation $\omega$ and every $a_1,...,a_n\in A$. So most likely in addition to $\mathcal C$-decidability in $A$ one has to care about decidability of $F$ in some form (e. g. for which $\omega$, $\omega'$ one has $F(\omega)=F(\omega')$, things like that)